# Rendering (display) a part of a web page in an android application

Tags: android, html, xhtml, html-parsing, jsoup

This question is not for android programmers only , but also for whom interested in web pages design .

I would like to make an android app that renders **some** parts of specific web pages only (not all part  of them) .

I am heard about jsoun library  as a tool that does this task

My main problem is:-

How I can choose the correct link from web page's source that render some part of a web page ?.

For example let us take  the famous website [FORBES](http://www.forbes.com/billionaires/list/#tab:overall)

How can I render the list of richest men  by their name and Rank,Name net Worth,Change,Age,Source,Country of Citizenship as they appearthere  excluding other parts of web page.
[Here is a good example of an application that accomplishes like this task](http://www.nabdapp.com/nabd-app-%D8%AA%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%82-%D9%86%D8%A8%D8%B6/nabd_app.php)

You may have a good suggestion.

Comment: `the correct link from web page's source that render some part of a web page` ? I'm not aware that links in web page's are responsible for rendering parts of a web page. What kind of mechanism are you talking about?

Comment: Here is a good example of an android application that do what I want http://www.nabdapp.com/nabd-app-تطبيق-نبض/nabd_app.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to screen-scrape the HTML. I'm not sure about any Android libraries for doing this, but I would build a RESTful service to return the data I needed. The service would than do the heavy lifting of scraping the webpage and converting the data to JSON to be sent back to device.

On the server side I would use a library like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do the scraping. It is easy enough to use once have it installed. You create a beautifulSoup object from the HTML and make calls like myObject.getTitle() to return the title of the HTML. You can use the tags in the HTML to drill down to the elements you want and build up a JSON object from there. Here is an image of the elements you are interested in for that list. Note the #ids on the right for that list item.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG9qX.png

Comment: Thank you for good hints , really as you said there would be a server side on which there is a database , firstly I will enter the screen-scraped html in the database  after that there must be RESTful service to send data to the android app . I have a couple of questions 1\Is Beautiful soup library could work with eclipse adt software on windows environment 2\After scraping html if there are links on that scraped page it would be scraped also?

Comment: 1: Beautiful Soup will run on the server, separate to the client so irrelevant what environment the client runs from.

Comment: 2: What I would do is create an array of links or write them to a file. Then have another script run passing in the list of links and visiting those links to gather what info you need.